# How to make jar file executable from anywhere without root permission

Tags: 14.04, java, jar

I made a jar file and now want to execute it from any directory. To do that I simply put it in /bin and made it executable, but I am not able to execute it and get this output error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile Test.jar
```

Comment: Check the permissions of the file using `ls -l /bin/Test.jar`. Do you have read access? Also, `/bin` is for system executables. For your own executables, use `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: problem was in permission of file . Simple chmod helped. but still unable to  access from /media/user/pqr .Thanks for pointing .

Comment: @the_Seppi you may as well post that as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you messed up the permissions of the Jar file. Check what permissions the file currently has using `ls -l /bin/Test.jar`. Maybe you didn't give execution permissions to all users or didn't assign read permission.

You can simply fix this with a `chmod guo+rx /bin/Test.jar` and the necessary permissions should be there.

---

Also, please note that `/bin` is meant for system executables. For your own executables, use `/usr/local/bin`. For further information read [this Unix SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8658).